# How do I get user input for a file location & creating a new folder based on user input for a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

How do I get user input for a file location & creating a new folder based on user input for a batch script?

My Script is:

```
if not exist "C:\Users\UserOne\Desktop\1" mkdir C:\Users\UserOne\Desktop\1
copy C:\Users\UserOne\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent C:\Users\UserOne\Desktop\1
```

Answer (score 0):

## Getting user input

It seems you wanted to get a string, so use the `set /p` command. Syntax:

```
set /p "variableName=prompt:"
```

It will appear as so in command prompt:

```
prompt:
```

You can enter an input and press enter, then `variableName` will contain the user input.

---

## Creating Folder

The `mkdir`(`md`) command is designed for this task. It's syntax is simple, like so:

```
mkdir "folderName"
```

To be more specifically to your case, use

```
mkdir "%variableName%"
```